# Derived class returns allocated base class instance

Tags: c++, inheritance, language-lawyer, static-cast

Is the following legit in C++?
The derived class is allocating base class and cast it to derived.
Obviously if derived (C) has members, anyone accessing members via the returned pointer would fail. But even without members in derive - is this legit? UB ?

```
struct B { int a; };
struct C : B { 
   static C* get() {
       return static_cast<C*>(new B);
   }
   enum { X, Y,};
};
int main(){
   C* c = C::get();
   return c->X;
}
```

Comment: Is your proposed cast in the list of allowed casts here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast - no? Then illegal.  I don't see it there, but you can take a look.

Comment: almost certainly UB, `static_cast` to non-dynamic type feels like UB

Comment: Just to make it clear. This comes up in code review that I was performing and found it. My opinion as people started pointing out - it's a UB. Looking for someone that can find the actual std clause/paragraph or something along those lines. thanks.

Comment: It is undefined behaviour.   In `main()`, the pointer `c` does not point at a `C` (it points at a `B`) so dereferencing as a `C` gives undefined behaviour.

Comment: well take a look at that page - do you see anything that says something like "unless the derived class has no members"?  No?  Then there's no such exception.

Comment: When accessing a static member of a class, or an enumerator, with `p->member` (or `(*p).member`), the evaluation of `*p` occurs just as in any other normal context, just as in `(void)*p;`. there is nothing special here, it isn't an unevaluated context like `sizeof`.

Comment: @Peter I think it's UB even when you don't deref it. Just getting the ptr is invalid.

Comment: @bartop What is a "non-dynamic type"? Why does it matter in that example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is UB. Excerpt from standard (emphasis mine):

#### [8.2.9 Static cast - bullet 11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.static.cast#11)

> A prvalue of type “pointer to cv1 B”, where B is a class type, can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to cv2 D”, where D is a class derived from B, if cv2 is the same cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than, cv1. If B is a virtual base class of D or a base class of a virtual base class of D, or if no valid standard conversion from “pointer to D” to “pointer to B” exists ([conv.ptr]), the program is ill-formed. The null pointer value is converted to the null pointer value of the destination type. If the prvalue of type “pointer to cv1 B” points to a B that is actually a subobject of an object of type D, the resulting pointer points to the enclosing object of type D. Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: perfect. thank you! https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.static.cast

Comment: @Kobi thanks for link, I always search for standard in HTML and never find it :P